# NServiceBus configuration in netcore 3.1 Startup

Tags: nservicebus

I've gone through all the documentation and examples of setting up NServiceBuse in NetCore, however, all the examples have the configuration being done in the `Program.cs` (`Host.CreateDefaultBuilder().UseNServiceBus()`).

I would like to know if I can configure NServiceBus in the `ConfigureServices` method of `Program.cs`.
The reason is that in the `HostBuilder` I'm building up all of the `IConfiguration` options (e.g. reading from appsettings.json, EnvironmentVariables, AzureKeyVault, ConfigMaps, etc.) and the Logger implementation.  By the time `ConfigureServices` is called, all of those have been resolved.  I need to be able to get things like connection strings from the IConfiguration, and so I don't believe it will work to do it in the HostBuilder.

It looks like a lot of work might be being done under the covers to inject the `IMessageSession` and scan for `IHandlMessages` instances.  That should be able to be done in the Service.

Edit: Forgot to add, because it is in the `Program.cs` and we are using Serilog, I do not have a LoggerFactory.  The LoggerFactory is registered and injected by the Services, but I cannot get it at this point in startup.

Comment: Do you have the overload with the context parameter containing the configuration available?
`Host.CreateDefaultBuilder().UseNServiceBus(context => 
{
   var config = context.Configuration;
})`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this isn't an option.  I was able to have a workaround to get it all working, which is just to put it in the Program() and just make sure it is called after all the other configuration is done.  It doesn't seem ideal and seem to be an anti-pattern from where netcore 3 is going.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add that this is a poor design choice. I should be able to register my stuff in startup and package scanning shouldn't be happening.

This is a neat project, but I think that for any non-trivial development it may be left lacking.

The reason is that I would like to have a web host with multiple endpoints and I cannot do that without running two full instances (https://docs.particular.net/samples/hosting/generic-multi-hosting/).

My workflow is

1. message comes in to do all the work
2. message #1 starts a saga with 100+ messages
3. each message publishes an update that it is done, so that the UI can check the status of the Saga

The messages from #3 are not handled until all 100+ messages are processed (FIFO).

What I'm wanting to do is have a second queue (we're using Azure service bus) to listen for the worker updates on and update the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Although you already have a workaround I have build a similar setup as you described with  with Serilog as logger and NServiceBus. You can access the configuration in Program.cs like so:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder() =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration()
        .UseSerilog()
        .UseNServiceBus(c => NServiceBusSetup.Configure(c.Configuration, c.HostingEnvironment))
```

In the self made method NServiceBus.Configure you can setup your endpoint.